# Field map Syncing issues

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-field-maps

Im making a field map for our field team.

I had to export all my feature classes as a geodatabase to get the field map to work offline.

They are now wanting me to add an extra editable layer, i can get it to publish to be offline but when we go on the field app on our iphones it keeps getting syncing issues.

If i publish just the new editable layer offline it works by itself. But when i put the editable layer and the previous layers in the same field map i get syncing issue.
"Unable to Synchronize replica"
"Sync replica internal error"

Also i just noticed i can actually open the maps offline error, the field team can add points but and it syncs but it still  is coming up with sync error?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have the users tried deleting their offline areas, refreshing the map, and then re-creating their offline areas?  The offline areas will be specific to the data schema of the map from which they were created.  If the schema changes, then the offline areas may not be able to sync to the new map schema which is different to the schema of the offline area.

Comment: Yes i've tried deleting the previous offline area, both in fieldmapps on phone and ARCIS and re-creating but i still get the same issue.

Comment: Did you "refresh map" in Field Maps?  (Before creating/downloading new offline area)  (I don't have it here... maybe it's "reload map"?)

Comment: Yeah so i have gone into the field map on AGOL, deleted the offline area. Then gone into field maps on my phone and refreshed the page so there is no offline area. Then i have got back in AGOL and pubished an offline area. Redownloaded and it just says Sync failed.

Comment: I also have noticed it will still open the map, and i can add points and it syncs. however i am still getting the error?

Comment: Have you tried deleting all offline areas (managed and/or local) and running the map online?  Do you still get an error that way?

Comment: Yes i tried that. I have discovered a work around.  I deleted out my uploaded layers from the zipped geodatabase and published each layer as a WMS and have added that in instead. Now its working. I dont understand.... Why?